# Cannot figure out how to loop this verilog state machine

Tags: verilog, fpga, state-machine, test-bench

The objective is to perform a singular function with at least a hundred iterations. Final goal is to completely make it gate-level. I could not figure that out so I am trying to get regular code to work. But I cannot  get this state machine to loop even twice. There are a lot of random commented codes due to testing things out. I need to get a counter/comparator working somehow. Return to state zero and resume the process. Below is the main code and the testbench I am using to try and test it. I can only get the 1st iteration working. But cannot get anything else.

Please any assistance would be appreciated. Thank you.

```
//Verilog module for Project
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module Project1(
    clk, rst, start,
     x_in, u_in, y_in,
     x_out, u_out, y_out
  );

//List the inputs and their sizes
    input clk, rst, start;
    input [7:0] x_in, u_in, y_in;

//List the outputs and their sizes 
   output integer x_out, u_out, y_out;

//Internal variables
//  integer  [7:0] rx4, rx2, rdx, r3, rudx, r3ux4_yx4, rux4_x4y;
//  integer  [7:0] ru_y;
    reg [7:0] min1, min2; 
    reg [15:0] tempmult;
    reg [7:0] ain1, ain2;
    reg [8:0] tempadd;

    integer     x_i, u_i, y_i;
    integer  rx4, rx2, rdx, r3, rudx, r3ux4_yx4, rux4_x4y;
    integer  ru_y;
    integer count = 0;
//List of Wires


// Declare state register and parameter

    reg [3:0] state;
    parameter S0 = 0, S1 = 1, S2 = 2, S3 = 3, S4 = 4, S5 = 5, S6 = 6;

//Instantiate Modules ----------------------------------------------------

//Multiplier
    lpmmult multiply(
    .clock(clk),
    .dataa(min1),
    .datab(min2),
    .result(mout));

//Adder
    adders adderss(
    .clock(clk),
    .data0x(ain1),
    .data1x(ain2),
    .result(aout));



//  always block
    always @ (posedge clk or posedge rst) begin:FSM_ST

        // Determine the next state
        if (rst) begin
            rdx = 1;
            r3 = 6;
            x_i <= x_in;
            u_i <= u_in;
            y_i <= y_in;


            state <= S0;
        end else if(start) begin    //End If Start else

        case (state)
            S0: begin
                // Multiplying using instantiated module
//              min1 <= x_i;
//              min2 <= x_i;
//              tempmult <= mout;
//              rx2 <= tempmult[15:8];
//              // Adding using instantiated module
//              ain1 <=x_i;
//              ain1 <=rdx;
//              tempadd <= aout;
//              if (tempadd[8] == 1) begin
//                  x_out <= tempadd[8:1];
//              end else begin
//                  x_out <= tempadd[7:0];
//              end


                rx2 <= x_i*x_i; //Multiplying using regular way
                x_out <= x_i+rdx; //Adding using regular way

                if (count < 10) begin
                    count = count + 1;
                    state = S1;
                    $display("Time %2d: x_out %1d is %2d", $time, x_out, y_out);
                    #10;
                end 
                else begin
                    state <= S1;
                    end
                    end// End State0

            S1: begin
                rx4 <= rx2*rx2;
                ru_y <= u_i+y_i;
//          Multiplying using instantiated module
//              min1 <= rx2;
//              min2 <= rx2;
//              tempmult <= mout;
//              rx4 <= tempmult[15:8];
//              
//          Adding using instantiated module
//              ain1 <=u_i;
//              ain1 <=y_i;
//              tempadd <= aout;
//              if (tempadd[8] == 1) begin
//                  ru_y <= tempadd[8:1];
//              end else begin
//                  ru_y <= tempadd[7:0];
//              end

                    state <= S2;
                    end// End State1

            S2: begin
                rux4_x4y <= rx4*ru_y;

//              min1 <= rx4;
//              min2 <= ru_y;
//              tempmult <= mout;
//              rux4_x4y <= tempmult[15:8];
                    state <= S3;
                    end// End State2

            S3: begin
                r3ux4_yx4 <= rux4_x4y*r3;

//              min1 <= rux4_x4y;
//              min2 <= r3;
//              tempmult <= mout;
//              r3ux4_yx4 <= tempmult[15:8];

                    state <= S4;
                    end// End State3

            S4: begin
                rudx <= u_i*rdx;
                u_out <= r3ux4_yx4+u_i;

//              min1 <= u_i;
//              min2 <= rdx;
//              tempmult <= mout;
//              rudx <= tempmult[15:8];
//              
//              // Adding using instantiated module
//              ain1 <=r3ux4_yx4;
//              ain1 <=u_i;
//              tempadd <= aout;
//              if (tempadd[8] == 1) begin
//                  u_out <= tempadd[8:1];
//              end else begin
//                  u_out <= tempadd[7:0];
//              end
                    state <= S5;
                    end// End State4

            S5: begin
                y_out <= rudx + y_i;

//          Adding using instantiated module
//              ain1 <=rudx;
//              ain1 <=y_i;
//              tempadd <= aout;
//              if (tempadd[8] == 1) begin
//                  y_out <= tempadd[8:1];
//              end else begin
//                  y_out <= tempadd[7:0];
//              end

                    state <= S6;
                    end// End State5

            S6: begin

                //Write output code Here
                if (start) begin
                    state = S0;

                end
//              if (count < 10) begin
//                  count = count + 1;
//                  state = S0;
//                  $display("Time %2d: x_out %1d is %2d", $time, x_out, y_out);
//                  #10;
//              end 

                end// End State6
            default:
                state <= S6;

            endcase

        end // End Else



    end// End always module

//  always @ (posedge clk) begin:FSM_S
//              if (count < 10) begin
//                  count = count + 1;
//                  //state = S0;
//                  $display("Time %2d: x_out %1d is %2d", $time, x_out, y_out);
//                  #10;
//              end 
//  end

endmodule
```

[/CODE]

```
//Verilog testbench module for Project
`timescale 1ns/1ps

module Project1_tb;

  reg clk, rst, start; //reset = active HIGH

  integer  x_in, u_in, y_in;
  wire [7:0] x_out, u_out, y_out;

  Project1 uut(

    .clk(clk), .rst(rst), .start(start),
     .x_in(x_in), .u_in(u_in), .y_in(y_in),
     .x_out(x_out), .u_out(u_out), .y_out(y_out)
  );

    initial begin   
        clk = 0;  
        forever #50 clk = ~clk;  
    end 

    initial begin
        #1000;
        start = 0;
        x_in = 8'b00000010;
        u_in = 8'b00000100;
        y_in = 8'b00000100;
        rst = 1;
        #1000;
        rst = 0;
        #1000;
        start = 1;
        #1000; 
        start = 0;
        #1000;
        rst = 1;
        #1000;
        rst = 0;
        #1000;
        start = 1;
        #50000;
    end

endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

It would have helped if you at least would have described what your trying tot do. Looks like a repeated add-multiply.

I just 'scanned' your code. You are mixing blocking and non-blocking assignment. In a clocked section (always @ posedge ...) you only use non-blocking assignments (There are some exceptions but you are probably not ready for those). Fix those first and then re-try.

Also your first top-level "if" in the clocked section is "if (start)". That is not a start that is an enable. Nothing will run unless 'start' is high.

As always some tips:
Work on your comment. Comments of the type "// Declare state register and parameter" are useless. It is like:

```
a=a+1 // Adding 1 to 'a'
```

At the same time you have not declared at the top of the file what the module should do. Also the name Project1 is not very descriptive.